# What was the paper about flower-shaped knots?

Tags: reference-request, random, knot-theory

I read a article about the possibility to bring knots in a "polar rose" projection, where there is only one crossing of higher multiplicity. The overcrossing/ undercrossing information is thus more complicated as usual. But it seems this form of displaying knots has advantages for the study of random knots. The author(s) introduced a special term for this projection, but I can`t remember and thus not find it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[KNOT PROJECTIONS WITH A SINGLE MULTI-CROSSING](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5742v2.pdf) by C. Adams and many more.

Comment: Thanks, your hint helped me to find the one I read before, which is http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.3308v2.pdf

Comment: @user127698 glad to help.  Cheers.